# Internet Explorer ignora background-color con propiedad flex

Tags: html, css

Tengo un documento HTML con un formulario. En el body tengo un div a modo contenedor donde encierro el formulario (para limitar el ancho del mismo).

Para hacerlo responsive utilizo flex, mi problema surge con Internet Explorer. El color del body es #F2F2F2, mientras que el background-color del contenedor es blanco (#FFF).

Google Chrome y Firefox interpretan correctamente el color de fondo del contenedor y lo muestran, pero Internet Explorer lo ignora. Se soluciona cuando retiro la propiedad flex.

```css
body{
    background: #F2F2F2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.contenedor{
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: ¿Versión de IE? (aunque casi da igual, ninguna versión [acepta al 100% flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox))

Comment: IE tiene algunos bugs con `flex`. Puedes poner `flex: 1 1 auto`. Aun así seguramente no coja bien la altura y tengas que especificarla

Comment: Podrías crear una hoja de estilos diferente para Internet Explorer, es una faena pero a veces es necesario hacer este tipo de cosas para contemplar las múltiples peculiaridades que tiene cada navegador. Te paso una referencia para que veas como puede hacerse esto: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/. Como bien te han dicho los compañeros, el flex e IE no se llevan demasiado bien, en esta hoja de estilos específica para IE podrías usar float.

Comment: Internet explorer ya no funciona. No me extrañaria que no suportase `flexbox`. Yo mismo tuve algunos problemas con este navegador. Saludos